# $(...).flexisel is not a function at (jquery-3.2.1.js:5206) ) , $(...).tooltipster is not a function (jquery-3.2.1.js:3583)

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

HI all I am facing error while implementing flexisel slider in **Share point 2013**
I am trying to change this line **$(window).load(function()** to **$(window).on('load',function()** .......because .load() function has been removed from old jquery

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#flexiselDemo1").flexisel();
    $("#flexiselDemo2").flexisel({
        visibleItems: 3,
        itemsToScroll: 1,
        animationSpeed: 200,
        infinite: true,
        navigationTargetSelector: null,
        autoPlay: {
            enable: false,
            interval: 5000,
            pauseOnHover: true
        },
        responsiveBreakpoints: { 
            portrait: { 
                changePoint:480,
                visibleItems: 1,
                itemsToScroll: 1
            }, 
            landscape: { 
                changePoint:640,
                visibleItems: 2,
                itemsToScroll: 2
            },
            tablet: { 
                changePoint:768,
                visibleItems: 3,
                itemsToScroll: 3            }
        }
    });
    $("#flexiselDemo3").flexisel({
        visibleItems: 3,
        itemsToScroll: 1,         
        autoPlay: {
            enable: true,
            interval: 5000,
            pauseOnHover: true
        }        
    });
    
    $("#flexiselDemo4").flexisel({
        infinite: false,visibleItems: 7     
    });    
    
});


</script>
<script>
        
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.tooltip').tooltipster({
   animation: 'fade',
   delay: 200,
   maxWidth:145
});

 });

</script>
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../SiteAssets/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flexisel.js">
        </script>
        <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js">
        </script>-->
        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="tooltipster-master/dist/js/tooltipster.bundle.min.js">//<!
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tooltipster/3.3.0/css/tooltipster.min.css" />
```

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).flexisel is not a function at Home.aspx:849 at dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.js:5206) at elemData.handle (jquery-3.2.1.js:5014)

ncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltipster is not a function at HTMLDocument. (Home.aspx:907) at mightThrow (jquery-3.2.1.js:3583) at process (jquery-3.2.1.js:3651)

It is working with Jquery version 1.11.3.min.js but not with latest vrsion 3.2.1.js..I need to upgrade Jquery

Comment: *"I need to upgrade Jquery"* ... are those plugins compatible with upgrade?

Comment: Its Just Latest Jquery rfenernce jquery-3.2.1.js